# Altitude isoline vector tiles?

Tags: elevation, vector-tiles

Is there a service that can provide altitude isoline as vector tiles?

I've seen that there are some posts on how to convert elevation tiles (raster DEM) with python or javascript applying some image processing (threshold images and then apply marching squares algorithm for conturing)
as in those links:

- https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/5844
- https://github.com/turf-junkyard/turf-isolines
- https://github.com/osm2vectortiles/dem2vectorterrain
- https://github.com/yvecai/DEM-scripts/blob/master/2015/merge_dem_hs_and_contour.py

But I don't find any already make service that can do it. What is the easiest way of doing it?

Answer (score 3):

The OpenMapTiles project allows you to download vector tiles with contour lines (altitude isolines) of the entire world or any region you need (even for custom selected area):
https://openmaptiles.com/contours/

If you want these vector tiles in a hosting service with powerful server infrastructure and CDN check the service https://www.tilehosting.com/

In case you would like to vectorize your own raster DEM or another raster data - and create vector data (SHP?) or vector tiles out of the georeferenced rasters while using bezier curves to produce lines or polygons - the team behind OctoGEO (https://octogeo.com/) can help you with this.

For very basic vectorization directly following the shape of each individual pixel, you can use the open-source [gdal_polygonize](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_polygonize.html) or [gdal_contour](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_contour.html) tools.